# Php string processing

Tags: php

I need to find `<p>` tag inside a string. Then I want to store the string from (including)

tag into another variable.

For example I have string name firstString;

firstString = `"<div id='tab-1'><p>This is first string</p></div>"`

I want second string to be

secondString = `"<p>This is first string</p>"`

I need only first `<p>` tag.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadHTML`. Maybe not the fastest option, but should be simple.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$res = $xp->query('//p');

$firstParagraph = $res[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Fatal Error :  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array.

Comment: may be you can't access the DOMNodeList items with array-style syntax... you should instead use ->item(0).

Comment: Yeah.. It work.. Thank you Mathieu Imbert and Shail :) I used foreach loop. Also works with Shail's way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex to grab this substring.

```
$firstString = "<div id='tab-1'><p>This is first string</p></div>";
preg_match("#(<p>.+</p>)#", $firstString, $out);
echo $out[1];
```

There are other ways to do it if you know more precisely how the string is formed, or if you wish to pull out multiple substrings you can use `preg_match_all` instead.

If this is for scraping something from HTML *in general* though, you should be using a dedicated system like DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* find opening tag */
$strPosBegin = strstr($firstString,"<p>");

if $strPosBegin != 0 {

    /* find position of closing tag */
    $strPosEnd = strstr($firstString,"</p>");

    /* adjust for the length of closing tag */
    $strPosEnd = $strPosEnd + 3;

    /* calculate difference, but need to add 1 */
    $strLength = $strPosEnd - $strPosBegin + 1;

     /* use substr to lift your search string out of $firstString
    $secondString = substr($firstString, $strPosBegin, $strLength);
}
```